# Delete DataRows from a DataTable

Tags: c#, collections, datatable

I want to delete DataRows from a DataTable. The rows to be deleted are in a datarow list "wantDelete".
Please correct my code because of an exception:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in myTable.Rows)
{
     if (wantDelete.Contains(dr))
     myTable.Rows.Remove(dr);
}
```

The exception is:

[image: exception]

Thank you very much.

Comment: how did you got wantdelete array? Did you do datatable.select("condition") or created new DataRow()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot modify a collection during enumeration because foreach uses an enumerator, and enumerators can't change the underlying collection.

So you either should use a `for-loop` or use another collection(`deleteItems`) that you have pre filtered.

I see in your code that you've already prefiltered it(i assume wantDelete is a `List<DataRow>)`:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in wantDelete)
{
     myTable.Rows.Remove(dr);
}
```

Side note: you know that removing rows from a `DataTable` does not delete them in your dbms if you're using a `DataAdapter`? Therefor you would need to use `DataRow.Delete()`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use foreach loop in this case. Use integer iteration:

```
for (int I = myTable.Rows.Count - 1; I >= 0; I -= 1) {
   if (wantDelete.Contains(myTable.Rows(I))) {
      myTable.Rows.Remove(myTable.Rows(I));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove DataRow while iterating the DataTable it is part of. So store the DataRows while iterating in another list of DataRows and delete it liek this:

```
        List<DataRow> rowsToDelete = new List<DataRow>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in myTable.Rows)
        {
            if (wantDelete.Contains(dr))
            {
                rowsToDelete.Add(dr);
            }
        }

        foreach (var dataRow in rowsToDelete)
        {
            myTable.Rows.Remove(dataRow);   
        }
```

Hope this helps ...

Answer (score 0):

You are looping and deleting the same table..in other words, after the row is removed the myTable.Rows will change so you can't use a "loop" on it. copy the table to a different table and delete it. (foreach should loop the "copy" table and remove it from the "original" table)